# MODX getResources filter

Tags: modx-revolution, modx-getresources

I need to filter my getResources so that the [[*longtitle]]s of filtered resources match [[*pagetitle]] of the resource where getResources snippet is used.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources) seem to indicate that you can:

WHERE : A JSON-style expression of criteria to build any additional where clauses from. See below for an example. See display/xPDO20/xPDOQuery.where

So try something like:

```
[[!getResources?  &where=`{"longtitle":[[*pagetitle]]}`]]
```

you might need quotes around the pagetitle.

Comment: If [[*pagetitle]] not number - quotes required!